# Actualizar registros mediante un TRIGGER FOR DELETE usando SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, trigger, tsql, cursor

Quiero hacer un `trigger` que en cuanto realice un despido al resto de empleados le suba el sueldo un 20%, pero no sé cómo operar directamente con el `cursor explícito` en este `trigger`, ya que la consulta me devolvería varios valores.

```
CREATE TRIGGER despemp
    ON Empleado
    FOR delete
    AS
        BEGIN
            IF  exists (select e# from deleted where (e# = (select e# from Empleado)))
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE @salariomas float = 0.2*(select salario from Empleado) + (select salario from Empleado);
                    BEGIN TRY
                        update Empleado set salario = @salariomas;
                    END TRY
                    BEGIN CATCH
                        print 'No se ha podido realizar la inserción'
                    END CATCH
                END
    END
```

Comment: Hola ras212, ¿el proceso sería únicamente realizado una vez? ¿Cuál es el objetivo de crear esta actualización de registros por medio de un `TRIGGER`? Si solo sería una vez, ¿no sería más conveniente realizar directamente un `UPDATE`?

Comment: Al despedirlo, ahora edito el enunciado

Comment: Me parece que aún así no queda claro lo que realmente deseas, por ejemplo, "*que me suba un 20% el sueldo de los empleados al despedir a uno de ellos*", es decir, que ¿a todos los empleados les subirán el 20% del sueldo cuando alguno de ellos sea despedido? ¿Me explico?, son algunas variantes de las que se deben tomar en cuenta para poder explicar adecuadamente lo que realmente requieres

Comment: Si. cuando uno sea despedido, el resto recibirá un aumento de sueldo del 20%

Comment: @Davlio ¿por qué cambiar el título a "*Actualizar registros con cursos explícito en un disparador*"? No le veo sentido

Comment: @Flxtr gracias por la actualización del título, estaba editándolo del móbil y y el autocompletar hizo `cursos`. Anteriormente indicaba `Procedimiento Almacenado` y la pregunta no tenía relación alguna.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por lo que describes en tu pregunta y los comentarios, parece que hacerle un `delete` a un registro en la tabla `Empleado` equivale a despedirlo.  Y tu deseo es aumentarle el salario un 20% a todos los demás empleados cuendo despides (eliminas) a un empleado.

Aunque esto suena un poco raro, sí es posible. Pero no hay necesidad de usar cursores. Simplemente se puede hacer con un simple `UPDATE` dentro del trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER despemp ON Empleado FOR delete AS
  set nocount on;
  update Empleado set salario *= 1.2;
go
```

El único detalle es que si tu sentencia `DELETE` elimina más de un empleado a la vez (o no elimina ninguno), solo habrá un solo aumento de 20% para todos los empleados.

De ser necesario, se puede ajustar el trigger para ser más preciso. O sea, que si el `DELETE` no elimina ningún empleado, nadie recibe un aumento. Y si el `DELETE` elimina varios empleados a la vez, se aplica el 20% de aumento el mismo número de veces que la cantidad de empleados eliminados.

Para hacer esto, solo hay que ajustar la fórmula para tomar en cuenta la cantidad de empleados eliminados:

```
CREATE TRIGGER despemp ON Empleado FOR delete AS
  set nocount on;

  declare @delCount int;
  select @delCount = count(*) from deleted;

  if @delCount > 0
    update Empleado set salario *= power(1.20, @delCount);
go
```

Comment: Nunca se me hubiera ocurrido hacerlo con la función `POWER`, si es lo que desea el OP funciona perfecto. +1